# Property 'configureTestingModule' doesn't exist on type TestBedStatic

Tags: angular, angular12, angular-test, testbed, angular14

I have updated my Angular 12 application to Angular 14 using `ng update`. The build was successful and can see my application running perfectly fine but my tests are failing. One of the errors I am getting is this:

> Property 'configureTestingModule' doesn't exist on type TestBedStatic

Anyone know any workaround for this? Do I need to update my testing libraries?

```
@angular/core: ^14.2.0
jasmine-core: ~3.8.0
jasmine-marbles: ^0.8.3
karma: ~6.3.0
protractor: ^7.0.0
```

Sample test:

```
beforeEach( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: []
    });
})
```

Comment: what libraries are you using for testing? can you provide some code of a test setup file?
updating testing libraries could be a valid solution. i was getting errors after upgrading angular because my jest version wasnt up to date

Comment: updated with libraries version

Comment: mhm what you could also try is deleting node_modules and rerun your install command. maybe some old files are cached from the earlier angualr version

Comment: that I tried, no luck.

Comment: i noticed a slight difference in my test setup which looks like this: beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ ... }). note the async.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

1. download the latest typescript version `npm install -g typescript`
2. type `tsc --version` to check the version. (currently 4.8 is the latest)
3. click on the version in vs code and update it if it wasn't updated.
4. If you're using `npm test`, then look at the typescript version in package.json